# Why is an InMemoryUserDetailsManager injected into this controller even though I've configured a JdbcUserDetailsManager elsewhere?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security [JDBC Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc) in a Spring Boot web app.
Here's the (much simplified, relevant) configuration:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema();
    }
}
```

Here's a controller:

```java
import org.adventure.inbound.UserFormData;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    public UserController(UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager) {
        this.userDetailsManager = userDetailsManager;
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> registerUser(UserFormData userFormData) {
        userDetailsManager.createUser(
                User
                        .withUsername(userFormData.getUsername())
                        .password(userFormData.getPassword())
                        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
                        .build());
        return ResponseEntity.created(null).build();
    }
}
```

When I start the app, I can see that:

- The AuthenticationManagerBuilder gets a JDBCUDM configured:

[image]

but perhaps some step is missing?

- The InMemoryUserDetailsManager is instantiated with Spring Security's default user:

[image]

- The Controller, when instantiated, receives an InMemoryUserDetailsManager:

[image]

This means that when I try to create a new user, it uses the InMemoryUDM instead of the JDBCUDM that I'd like to use. Why is that?

### Working solution

We already configure the UserDetailsService through JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer, but didn't expose it as a bean.

```java
    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema();
        return jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.getUserDetailsService();
    }
```

Comment: Because you haven't exposed it as a bean.

Comment: I see. It's not enough to configure the UserDetailsService (this is done by the auth.jdbcAuthentication() call), the resulting, configured UserDetailsService also needs to be exposed as a bean to be picked up.

Feel free to post your reply as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration override the `userDetailsServiceBean()`, and let it call the super method and add the `@Bean` annotation to make the configured service available. This is also explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#userDetailsServiceBean--) in the Javadocs.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecutiryConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean()
                                          throws java.lang.Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    } 
}
```

Also because you want to use your configuration instead of the Spring Boot one, you might need to add `@EnableWebSecurity` to disable the Spring Boot defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Make your SecurityConfiguration **extend from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**, add **@EnableWebSecurity** and **expose your JdbcUserDetailsManager** as @Bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        return yourJdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

/// etc.
}
```